# Finding minimum non-zero element in yalmip

Tags: matlab

I have a vector x, 1x4 of sdpvar, in Matlab using Yalmip, no negative values. I want to find the minimum non-zero element. 
My immediate attempt was min(x(x>0)). However conditional indexing is not supported inside sdpvar. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Answered](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/yalmip/pE-QiolwnZo) (hopefully) on the YALMIP forum.